# Could not able to load original image on imageview after capturing it from camera. Is there any way to resolve this?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera-intent

Acter capturing image from the camera, when i load into an imageview, the quality of the image becomes ver low. I don't want to do that. I'm using marshmallow. Is there any solution for this?
Its been 24 hrs, i haven't get any answer yet which fixed my issue.
Please help me out.

//MainActivity.java file

```
  package com.example.surya.cameraapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button buCamera;
ImageView capturedImage;
final int PICTURE_RESULT=1;
Uri imageUri;
String imageurl;

 public static final int 
 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 
 123;

   public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(
        final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= 
 android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if 
(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    (Activity) context,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) 
 {
                showDialog("External storage", context,

 Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat
                        .requestPermissions(
                                (Activity) context,
                                new String[] { 
 Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },

 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

       } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(final String msg, final Context 
context,
                       final String permission) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new 
  AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
    alertBuilder.setMessage(msg + " permission is necessary");
     alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) 
context,
                            new String[] { permission },

 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 
 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // do your stuff
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GET_ACCOUNTS 
 Denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, 
 permissions,
                    grantResults);
    }
    }

   public void takePhoto(View view){
    if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New 
Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From 
your Camera");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
 values);
        Intent intent = new 
 Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int 
 resultCode, 
 Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {

             case PICTURE_RESULT:
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                             Bitmap thumbnail = 
 MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                     getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                             capturedImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                             imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                         }

                    }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, 
 null);
        int column_index = cursor

   .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        capturedImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buCamera=findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    }
 }
```

Comment: you are likely doing something wrong (sorry for obvious note). You have to show your code for us to help fixing it.

Comment: _Bad quality_ depends how are you compress(resize) your bitmap object?

Comment: Show your code please,then others will offer you a appropriate solutioin.

Comment: At first, i tried using simple camera intent to captaure and then startActivityForResult() and then i set my imageview to that bitmap on a tivity result but that too loads a very bad quality image. And when i'm using this code, my app gets stop working when i click my capture button..

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to the image, it works for me.

Comment: It will be stretched the image if the image is not as per aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imageview selectImage;
 Bitmap currentImage;
Uri filepath;

if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        try {
            currentImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            currentImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                    getString(R.string.app_name), "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            imgPath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            selectImage.setImageBitmap(currentImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```